# Nuxt typescript - Property 'map' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, nuxt.js

I am trying to use nuxt with typescript and am geting an error on the map (mapbox object)

I define it in my data

```js
data() {
  return {  
    map: null,
  }
}
```

and initialise it.

```js
mounted() {
  this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    /* option in here */
  })
}
```

I know it is a complex object so could just make in an 'any' type, but how do I get rid of the error?

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage

Comment: Your code seems okay. We need more code